# Import text file with ts-node

Tags: node.js

I'd like to import a text file:

```
import text from "./text.txt";
```

I have a file with:

```
declare module "*.txt" {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

However, ts-node complains with:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module './text.txt' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Please note that I cannot use the `fs` module to read the file since I am also using the same code for the web frontend (where the import is resolved by the bundler).

EDIT

Trying to use the proposal in the first answer:

```
import text from "./text.txt!text";
```

with

```
declare module "*!text" {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot find module './text.txt!text' from '...'
```

Comment: put the reference to the definition file on top of the file where you are importing this txt file like following:
`/// <reference path="./index.d.ts"/>`

Comment: If above doesn’t work for you try going through this article https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1332963

Comment: any news about this issue in 2022 :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to tell typescript  that your module will be a string type like that:
import text from "./text.txt!text";

Comment: Still getting "Cannot find module './text.txt!text' from '...'"